# Can I recursively apply transformations to a Spark dataframe in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Noodling around with Spark, using `union` to build up a suitably large test dataset. This works OK:

`val df = spark.read.json("/opt/spark/examples/src/main/resources/people.json")
df.union(df).union(df).count()`

But I'd like to do something like this:

`val df = spark.read.json("/opt/spark/examples/src/main/resources/people.json")
for (a <- 1 until 10){
  df = df.union(df)
}`

that barfs with error

`<console>:27: error: reassignment to val
         df = df.union(df)
            ^`

I know this technique would work using python, but this is my first time using scala so I'm unsure of the syntax.

How can I recursively union a dataframe with itself *n* times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use val on the dataset it becomes an immutable variable. That means you can't do any reassignments. If you change your definition to `var df` your code should work.

A functional approach without mutable data is:

```
val df = List(1,2,3,4,5).toDF
val bigDf = ( for (a <- 1 until 10) yield df ) reduce (_ union _)
```

The for loop will create a IndexedSeq of the specified length containing your DataFrame and the reduce function will take the first DataFrame union it with the second and will start again using the result.

Even shorter without the for loop:

```
val df = List(1,2,3,4,5).toDF
val bigDf = 1 until 10 map (_ => df) reduce (_ union _)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this with tail recursion using an arbitrary range:

```
@tailrec
def bigUnion(rng: Range, df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  if (rng.isEmpty) df
  else bigUnion(rng.tail, df.union(df))
}
val resultingBigDF = bigUnion(1.to(10), myDataFrame)
```

Please note this is untested code based on a similar things I had done.